# How can I view both table and form in same view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have recently learning ASP.NET MVC5.

I am trying to see both the form and a table(return as partialview) in one view but i'm getting this error.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference does not set to an instance of an object.
```

Here is my Model:

```
public class Prescription
{
    [Key]
    public int PrescriptionID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Assessment")]
    public int? AssessmentID { get; set; }
    public Assessment Assessment { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Medicine")]
    [Display(Name ="Prescription")]
    public int? MedcineID { get; set; }
    public Medicine Medicine { get; set; }
}
```

My main view where I want to put my partial view:

```
@using ClinicManagemet
@model ClinicManagemet.Models.Prescription


@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Prescription</h4>
    <hr />


    <div class="form-group">

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MedcineID, "MedcineID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("MedcineID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MedcineID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

     @Html.Action("ViewPrescription","Assessments")

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to Home", "Home")
</div>
```

My partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<ClinicManagemet.Models.Prescription>

 <table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Assessment.Complaint)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Medicine.MedicineName)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

 @foreach (var item in Model) { //Here is the line where I get the error
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assessment.Complaint)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Medicine.MedicineName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.PrescriptionID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.PrescriptionID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.PrescriptionID })
    </td>
</tr>
 }

 </table>
```

My partial view's controller:

```
public ActionResult ViewPrescription()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Edit: If I fix this, I'll try to add Ajax so whenever I insert something, it will just refresh the partial view.

Comment: Please check my answer bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your partial view like this,

```
@{
    Html.RenderAction("ViewPrescription","YourControllerName") 
 }
```

And in your ViewPrescription method, return the data,

```
{
 //Fetch the data here
 return PartialView(model);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing a model into the partial view when returning the view.

```
public ActionResult ViewPrescription()
    {
        ClinicManagemet.Models.Prescription model = _service.GetPerscription();

        return PartialView(model);
    }
```